# How to update User with webapp2 and simpleauth?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I have a profile page for my users where they should be able to update their information. For now they can update their names but I also want phonenumbers, addresses, etc.

[image]

The code for updating the name of my user is

```
class AccountPage(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('accountpage.html', {'request': self.request, 'user': self.current_user,'loggedin': self.logged_in, 'session': self.auth.get_user_by_session(),})
    def post(self):

        user = self.current_user
        user.name = self.request.POST['name']
        user.put()
        self.auth.set_session(
                self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user))

        self.render('accountpage.html', {'request': self.request, 'loggedin': self.logged_in,'user': self.current_user})
```

But how can I use extra variables such as phonenumbers, address variable etc? The [webapp2 User model](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html) is an expando model. It did not work to just add the variables to the model:

```
class User(model.Expando):
    """Stores user authentication credentials or authorization ids."""

    #: The model used to ensure uniqueness.
    unique_model = Unique
    #: The model used to store tokens.
    token_model = UserToken

    created = model.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = model.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    # ID for third party authentication, e.g. 'google:username'. UNIQUE.
    auth_ids = model.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    # Hashed password. Not required because third party authentication
    # doesn't use password.
    password = model.StringProperty()
    phonenumber = model.StringProperty()
    address = model.StringProperty()
```

I use [simpleauth](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth) and I get this error msg from simpleauth:

```
INFO     2015-07-20 06:09:34,426 authhandlers.py:78] user_dict | {'name': u'DAC', 'user_id': 5620703441190912, 'token': u'c9BbE72EmrgTDpG1Dl4tlo', 'token_ts': 1437371676, 'cache_ts': 1437371676, 'remember': 0} 
ERROR    2015-07-20 06:09:34,437 authhandlers.py:42] 'phonenumber'
INFO     2015-07-20 06:09:34,445 module.py:812] default: "POST /account/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2015-07-20 06:09:34,501 module.py:812] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 450
```

In my `BaseRequestHandler` I have this cached_property that creates an object.

```
@webapp2.cached_property
def current_user(self):
    """Returns currently logged in user"""
    user_dict = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
    logging.info('user_dict | %s ' % user_dict)
    if user_dict:
        return self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_id(user_dict['user_id'])
    else:
        return api.users.get_current_user()
```

Then I tried changing the user model but I still get the `ERR phone_number` when making these changes.

```
class BaseRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    class User(auth_models.User):
        address = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
        phone_number = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)

    def dispatch(self):
        # Get a session store for this request.
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        if self.request.host.find('.br') > 0:
            i18n.get_i18n().set_locale('pt-br')
        elif self.request.host.find('klok') > 0:
            i18n.get_i18n().set_locale('sv')
        elif self.request.host.find('business') > 0:
            i18n.get_i18n().set_locale('en')
        else:
            lang_code_get = self.request.get('hl', None)
            if lang_code_get is None:
                lang_code = self.session.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', None)
                lang_code_browser = os.environ.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE')
                if lang_code:
                    i18n.get_i18n().set_locale(lang_code)
                if lang_code_browser and lang_code is None:
                    self.session['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = lang_code_browser
                    i18n.get_i18n().set_locale(lang_code_browser)
            else:
                i18n.get_i18n().set_locale(lang_code_get)
        try:
            # Dispatch the request.
            logging.info('trying to dispatch')
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        except Exception, ex:
            logging.error(ex)
            self.error(404)
        finally:
            # Save all sessions.
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        """Returns a Jinja2 renderer cached in the app registry"""
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        """Returns a session using the default cookie key"""
        return self.session_store.get_session()

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def auth(self):
        return auth.get_auth()

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session_store(self):
        return sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def auth_config(self):
        """
  ..........Dict to hold urls for login/logout
  ......"""
        return {'login_url': self.uri_for('login'),
                'logout_url': self.uri_for('logout')}

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def current_user(self):
        """Returns currently logged in user"""
        user_dict = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
        logging.info('user_dict | %s ' % user_dict)
        if user_dict:
            return self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_id(user_dict['user_id'])
        else:
            return api.users.get_current_user()
```

Comment: You need to add `phonenumber`, `address`, etc properties into your `User` model. Show the code where your `User` model is defined.

Comment: I'll suggest you to create your own db model. Or if you really want to use the webapp2 model, you need to subclass it and then add your own extra properties

Comment: @MihailRussu Thank you for the comment. I modified the User model adding the extra variables but now I get an error message from my authentication module simpleauth that I must handle.

Comment: @marcadian I believe that my simpleauth authentication depends on that I use webapp2 User model and I already have lots of users registered with this model. I'd prefer not to swtich models and instead modifying the one I got if possible. But then my authhandler complains.

Comment: Are you adding the properties into your own model or are you adding the changes into builtin `webapp2_extras\appengine\auth\models.py` file? The code of model you provided seems to be just a copy of one of webapp2's internal files and you should NOT be doing any changes there. What you need to do is to extend from `auth_models.User` and add your properties there. Your existing data wouldn't be lost. Let me know whether you don't have your own model for `User` yet.

Comment: @MihailRussu I don't have my own model for `User`. I just let simeplauth do it for me and entities named `User` are already written to the datastore, but they do not have phonenumbers or addresses. Only login fields that are defined by simpleauth. if I add the fields the the builtin `webapp2_extras\appengine\auth\models.py` then I get the error message fromsimeplauth saying `ERR: phonenumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above - you should NOT be making any changes in any of the built-in libraries, instead, you can extend them and then add any additional code/properties you need.

So first, you'd need to define your own `User` model, which would look simmilar to this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models as auth_models

class User(auth_models.User):
    address = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    phone_number = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
```

You are only adding the new properties you need or the ones you need to override, so no `created` / `updated` / etc as they're inherited from the model you were referring to.

You then need to work with this model inside your `BaseRequestHandler` class (I'm not sure what the line `self.current_user` does, you might need to include the code for that as well).

You can also read this article to get some more ideas: http://gosurob.com/post/20024043690/gaewebapp2accounts

Comment: That looks great but I still get an error message when doing the dispatch in my BaseRequestHandler. I've updated the question with more of my code.

Comment: You added the new class **inside** your `BaseRequestHandler`, it should be outside, but even then, you are not referring it anywhere in your code. Have you looked at the article I shared? It's pretty streight forward and does exactly what you're looking for! Basically you need to start `WSGIApplication` with config parameters stating what your new user model is via `webapp2_extras.auth.user_model` property.

Comment: After some fixing now the code works. I could keep the new User class inside the BAseRequestHandler clas, it was only a misspelling from the html that got posted. Now everything works. Thank you.