# cant access session when using oauth2 library in flask

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, gcloud

I am trying this for weeks,trying to eliminate every stupid  mistakes I do(a newbie!).This is my application factory function.I am folowing google app engine books application tutorial and getting its tits and bits and trying to mold something of my own.I am stuck in login functionality.I am using package structure.

```
from woles_search import search#this is blueprint object
from PTE import PTE#this is blueprint object
from Home import home#this is blueprint object
from flask import current_app, Flask, redirect, request, session, url_for,g
import json
import config
import logging
import httplib2
infouser=""#tried to make this variable global and pass it in it templates but didnt worked 

# [START include]
from oauth2client.contrib.flask_util import UserOAuth2

oauth2 = UserOAuth2()
# [END include]
#creates a app instance in main directory
def create_app(config):
    app=Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    #app.config['SECRET-KEY']="secret"
    print app.config['SECRET_KEY']
    from app_folder.woles_search import search
    from app_folder.PTE import PTE
    from app_folder.Home import home
    with app.app_context():
        model = get_model()
        model.init_app(app)

    oauth2.init_app(
    app,
    scopes=['email', 'profile'],
    authorize_callback=_request_user_info) #configuring oauth

    app.register_blueprint(search,url_prefix="/search")
    app.register_blueprint(PTE,url_prefix="/PTE")
    app.register_blueprint(home,url_prefix="/home")

    return app

def get_model():
    model_backend = current_app.config['DATA_BACKEND']
    print model_backend
    if model_backend == 'datastore':
        from auth_package import model_datastore
        model = model_datastore
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            "No appropriate databackend configured. "
            "Please specify datastore, cloudsql, or mongodb")

    return model


    # [START request_user_info]
def _request_user_info(credentials):
    """
    Makes an HTTP request to the Google+ API to retrieve the user's basic
    profile information, including full name and photo, and stores it in the
    Flask session.
    """
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials.authorize(http)
    resp, content = http.request(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me')

    if resp.status != 200:
        current_app.logger.error(
            "Error while obtaining user profile: %s" % resp)
        return None


    infouser = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
    #current_app.logger.info(infouser)#this works
    session['profile'] = infouser
    current_app.logger.info(session['profile'])
    #this is a test for session,since it does not show up in templates,it works, get printed out in console
```

This is main .py and app.yaml(copy and pasted,nothing special)
main.py

```
import config
from flask import render_template,current_app,session
from app_folder.app import create_app

app = create_app(config)
app.config.from_object(config)
print app.config['SECRET_KEY']


    # Add a logout handler.
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # Delete the user's profile and the credentials stored by oauth2.
    del session['profile']
    oauth2.storage.delete()
    return redirect(request.referrer or '/')
    # [END logout]


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('base.html')</code>
```

this is app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
handlers:
- url: /.*  # This regex directs all routes to main.app
  script: main.app
ibraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Here is the template

```
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bookshelf - Python on Google Cloud Platform</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="navbar-brand">Bookshelf</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/books">Books</a></li>
          <li><a href="/books/mine">My Books</a></li>
        </ul>
        {# [START profile] #}
        {{session.profile.displayName}}
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
        {% if session.profile %}
          <a href="/logout">
            {% if session.profile.image %}
              <img class="img-circle" src="{{session.profile.image.url}}" width="24">
            {% endif %}
            {{session.profile.displayName}}
          </a>
        {% else %}
          <a href="/oauth2authorize">Login</a>
        {% endif %}
        </p>
        {# [END profile] #}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    {{user}}
  </body>
</html>
</code>
```

Note the use of {{session.profile.displayname}} outside of if block,that was to see what was the error,but eventually it stopped showing no error as well(??) in base.html but still shows error in logout view throwing error "no key profile was found".I can see the user info in my console output.I have config file in the root.I checked it,it loads the google credentials and secret key.I am using google cloud sdk shell as my dev_appserver.py is no more recognised in cmd on windows after gcloud sdk update.I revoked the credentials on cloud sdk shell just to make sure it is not interferring(If it does!!) and also tried while it was authorised.I tried making COOKIE_SECURE_PATH=False and lot of things I could think of but no results.Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are too many unresolved references for me to test your code. I suggest you write test cases for small functions and if possible try another oauth framework for python appengine such as simpleauth if it works for you https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth I too struggled with advanced login frameworks that didn't work until simpleauth just worked. Any reason to not use it? I can help you. You can read my question about Oauth in appengine here [How to update User with webapp2 and simpleauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509708/how-to-update-user-with-webapp2-and-simpleauth)

Comment: .Thanks for the advice.But my motive is more learning than building.I especially find debugging a very useful way of learning though highly frustrating.Anyways..i found the culprit..it was SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY in default flask app configuration which defaults to true.see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config ,After changing it to False,I can see session in different views in  different blueprints though still unable to access in html templates.Also,sorry I still dont know how to write unittests..they really seem complicated.

Comment: If you found a solution, please post your findings as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).